# ASP.NET MVC submit button click not firing

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue with button click event firing . I have two buttons on same view but for some reason after one one button click other button click event does not fire. Could you any help on this?. If you see below after copydata button click the getdata button click does not fire.

```
<div id ="MainDiv">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4> Please Select the Environment :</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList(
                    "SelectedEnvironmentID",
                    new SelectList(
                        Model.EnvironmentViewModel.Select(x => new { Value = x.Id, Text =  
                        x.Name }),
                        "Value",
                        "Text"), new { @onchange = "HideElements()" }
                    )
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4> Please Select the Version :</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList(
                    "SelectedVersionID",
                    new SelectList(
                        Model.VersionsModel.Select(x => new { Value = x.Id, Text = x.Number }),
                        "Value",
                        "Text"), new { @onchange = "HideElements()" }
                    )
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="getData" name="ViewServerData" type="submit" value="View Profiles" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>

 <p></p>   

 <div id ="ProfileCopyDiv" class="Copy" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4> Please Select the Environment To Copy Selected Server Profile:</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList(
                    "SelectedEnvironmentID2",
                    new SelectList(
                        Model.EnvironmentViewModel.Select(x => new { Value = x.Id, Text = 
                     x.Name }),
                        "Value",
                        "Text"), new { }
                    )
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4> Please Select the Version To Copy Selected Server Profile:</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList(
                    "SelectedVersionID2",
                    new SelectList(
                        Model.VersionsModel.Select(x => new { Value = x.Id, Text = x.Number }),
                        "Value",
                        "Text"), new { }
                    )
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4> Please Select the PlatformProfile To Copy:</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList(
                    "SelectedProfileID2", selectList: new SelectList(
                        Model.PlatformProfilewModel.Select(x => new { Value = x.Id, Text = 
              x.Name }),
                        "Value",
                        "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { }
                    )
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  <input id="copyData" name="SnapshotData" type="submit" value="Submit" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
         @grid1.GetJavaScript();
         @grid2.GetJavaScript();

        $("#getData").click(function() {

            alert("Test");
            document.getElementById('gridWrapper1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('gridWrapper2').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('gridheader').style.display = 'block';
            $('#gridheader').empty();
            //var content = "<table><tr><td><h4>Selected Environment :" +    
              $('#SelectedEnvironmentID :selected').text() + " </h4></td>" +
            //"<td><h4> Selected Version: " + $('#SelectedVersionID :selected').text() 
            + "</h4></td></tr></table>";
            //$('#gridheader').append(content);

            var url = '@Url.Action("GetServersWithSettings")';
            url = url + '?envtid=' + $("#SelectedEnvironmentID").val() + '&versionid=' + 
         $("#SelectedVersionID").val();
            $("#ServersWS").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: url }).trigger('reloadGrid');
            alert(url);

            var url1 = '@Url.Action("GetServersWithZeroSettings")';
            url1 = url1 + '?envtid=' + $("#SelectedEnvironmentID").val() + '&versionid=' + $("#SelectedVersionID").val();
            $("#ServersWNS").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: url1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');

            alert(url1);

        });

        $("#copyData").click(function() {

            var selectedRowId = $('#ServersWS').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            var rowData = jQuery("#ServersWS").jqGrid('getRowData', selectedRowId);

            $("#MainDiv *").attr("disabled", false).off('click');
            var url = '@Url.Action("Index")';
            //url = url + '?envtid=' + $("#SelectedEnvironmentID").val() + '&versionid=' + $("#SelectedVersionID").val()
            //              + '&profileid=' + rowData['ProfileId'] + '&envtid2=' + $("#SelectedEnvironmentID2").val() + '&versionid2=' + $("#SelectedVersionID2").val();
            HideElements();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                            BaseEnvtId: $("#SelectedEnvironmentID").val(),
                            BaseVersionId: $("#SelectedVersionID").val(),
                            BaseProfileId: rowData['ProfileId'],
                            NewEnvtId: $("#SelectedEnvironmentID2").val(),
                            NewVersionId: $("#SelectedVersionID2").val(),
                            NewProfileId: $("#SelectedProfileID2").val(),
                },
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    //var content = "<div style=/""color: green ;font-weight:900;/"">Baseline Profile Copied Successfully</div>";
                    $("#MainDiv *").attr("disabled", true).off('click');
                    document.getElementById('ProfileCopyDiv').style.display = 'block';
                    $("#MainDiv *").attr("disabled", false).off('click');
                    document.getElementById('displaySuccess').style.display = 'block';
                    $("#ProfileCopyDiv *").attr("disabled", true).off('click');
                    document.getElementById('ProfileCopyDiv').style.display = 'none';
                },
                error: function() { alert('something bad happened'); }
            });



        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need a form to submit anything to the server! Where's yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you see below after copydata button click the getdata button click does not fire.

That is because you are disabling the click event on click of copyData for all elements that are descendants of `#MainDiv`. So this behavior is natural.

```
     $("#copyData").click(function() {

        var selectedRowId = $('#ServersWS').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        var rowData = jQuery("#ServersWS").jqGrid('getRowData', selectedRowId);

        $("#MainDiv *").attr("disabled", false).off('click'); //<---- HERE
        var url = '@Url.Action("Index")';
```

Because [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) turns off event, and here your unfortunate button will be selected by `#MainDiv *` selector for the click event to be turned off.

Also better use `prop` instead of `attr`

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got some bad javascript in there that's throwing an error, without seeing all of it it's impossible to tell. Try stepping through it in a debugger (use Chrome's developer tools) and see if you get an error message. Maybe it's the **HideElements()** function.